# Python subprocess.poll() questions

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am working with Pythons subprocess module and and having issues polling a running process.

My end goal is to grab each new line from `stdout` evaluate it printing out relevant new lines the main process's `stdout` as it runs. The issues is that when I poll a test program it seems to wait for the child process to finish before outputting anything to the `stdout`. It is doing this when I introduce a `time.sleep(1)` method to the parent program.

**Parent Program**

```py
import subprocess
import time
def runProcess():
    process = subprocess.Popen([
        'py.exe',
        'subpy.py'],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while process.poll() == None:
        print('.', end ="")
        time.sleep(1)

runProcess()
input("press enter to exit.")
```

**Child Program**

```py
import random, time

for x in range(1,5):
    time.sleep(1)
    value = random.randint(1,3)
    if value == 1: 
        print("hello")
    if value == 2:
        print('goodbye')
    if value == 3:
        print('im not sure')
exit()
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

**PS:**

My end goal for the `parent` process would look something like this, although i'm not sure if this would run into issues of polling before an output is totally completed.

```py
import subprocess
import time
def runProcess():
    process = subprocess.Popen([
        'py.exe',
        'subpy.py'],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    while process.poll() == None:
        stdout, stderr = subprocess.communicate()
        if stdout == '':
            print('.', end ="")
            time.sleep(1)
        if stdout == "goodbye" or stdout == 'hello'
            print(">>> %s" % stdout)
        else:
            print(stdout)

runProcess()
input("press enter to exit.")
```

Comment: You didn't flush stdout. What happens if you do?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica
I tired to add `process.stdout.flush()` before and after my `while` loop and it did not help.

Comment: No, try flushing the parent's stdout.

Comment: @IdecEddy, ...to add some context to the above: stdout is only line-buffered by default *when it's directed to a TTY*. When it's directed to a file or a FIFO, default buffering is much larger blocks. (That's also true in the C standard library, it's not just a Python thing).

Comment: That, and `print('.', end ="")` doesn't have a line terminator, so line-buffered output will still just buffer that unless you flush stdout explicitly.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica
@CharlesDuffy
Thanks!  I changed my print to `print('.', end ="", flush=True)` and it works.

Comment: There is no `subprocess.communicate()` so your example isn't code you are actually running. You likely meant `process.communicate()` but that function waits for the process to complete before returning. Nothing in your code prints the stdout of the child. I think you want to read `process.stdout` line by line... is that correct?

Comment: @tdelaney 

Yes you are correct. I am reading more into this but I am getting the same behavior when I try to read `process.stdout` in my `process.poll()` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you create the process, you can read its `stdout` until it closes, indicating that the process has closed. But there are a couple of problems.

The first is that the process may fill up `stderr` and block trying to write more. That is solved with a background thread that reads stderr for you. In this example, I just copy it to an in-memory buffer to read after the process exits. There are other options, depending on what you want to do with the data stream.

Then there's the question of how often the `stdout` pipe is flushed. Since its a pipe, writing is block buffered. Without flushes coming from the subprocess, you won't get the output real time. In unix-like systems, you can replace the pipe with a pseudo-tty (see pty module). But this is Windows, so there isn't much you can do from the calling process. What ends up happening is that you get the incoming lines in groups based on when the clibrary of the child flushes (or you put a lot of flushes in the code).

```
import subprocess
import sys
import io
import time
import shutil
import threading

def runProcess():
    process = subprocess.Popen([
        sys.executable,
        'subpy.py'],
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.stdin.close()
    err_buf = io.BytesIO()
    err_thread = threading.Thread(target=shutil.copyfileobj,
            args=(process.stderr, err_buf))
    err_thread.start()
    for line in process.stdout:
        line = line.decode() # defaulting to system encoding
        print(line,end='',flush=True)
    process.wait()
    err_thread.join()
    err_buf.seek(0)
    print("Errors:", err_buf.read().decode())

runProcess()
input("press enter to exit.")
```

Comment: That worked like a charm. Now I just need to pray. The final subprocess that I will be running is a java program that is built by a third party. I have no clue how they manage flushing their stdout. Thanks again.

Comment: There may be a way to configure the JVM to flush differently. i have no idea about that. Pipe buffers aren't huge and there are a lot of programs out there that work just find with block buffering. Hope it works!